# Not understanding why `__index__` method works

Tags: python

I'm working through this [tutorial](http://blog.thedigitalcatonline.com/blog/2015/05/13/python-oop-tdd-example-part1/#.VxEEfjE2sdQ) which has the following Binary class:

```
import collections

class Binary:
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        if isinstance(value, collections.Sequence):
            if len(value) > 2 and value[0:2] == '0b':
                self._value = int(value, base=2)
            elif len(value) > 2 and value[0:2] == '0x':
                self._value = int(value, base=16)
            else:
                self._value = int(''.join([str(i) for i in value]), base=2)
        else:
            try:
                self._value = int(value)
                if self._value < 0:
                    raise ValueError("Binary cannot accept negative numbers. Use SizedBinary instead")
            except ValueError:
                raise ValueError("Cannot convert value {} to Binary".format(value))

    def __int__(self):
        return self._value
```

when running a unittest with pytest we get:

```
    def test_binary_hex():
        binary = Binary(6)
>       assert hex(binary) == '0x6'
E       TypeError: 'Binary' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

To solve this , the article states:

> According to the official documentation, "If x is not a Python int object, it has to define an `__index__()` method that returns an integer." so this is what we are missing. As for `__index__()`, the documentation states that "In order to have a coherent integer type class, when `__index__()` is defined `__int__()` should also be defined, and both should return the same value."

So we just have to add

```
def __index__(self):
    return self.__int__()
```

This does work, but why do  the `__index__` and `__int__` as written here, return the same value? Regarding:

```
def __index__(self):
    return self.__int__()
```

Shouldnt it be :
    return self._value.`__int__()`

edit:

with:

```
    def __int__(self):
        return self._value
```

This makes sense to me because `_value` is an integer.

with:

```
def __index__(self):
    return self.__int__()
```

In this case again self is an instance of a class , which in theory could many  attributes (although not in this case). I don't understand how in return self.`__int__()`,  the `__int__()` knows to get the integer stored in `_value` if we don't pass `_value` explicitly to `__int__()`

Comment: They return the same value because that's how they're written; `__index__` returns the value of `__int__`. You're more or less simply aliasing the `__int__` method under another name.

Comment: You don't need `__index__` to pass `_value` to `__int__` because `__int__` is already programmed to read the `_value` attribute on `self`. You do understand that `self.__int__()` calls the `__int__` method you previously defined, right?

Comment: consider adding an intermediate step: `def __index__(self): x = self.__int__() ; return x` you are calling the `__int__` method which gets the `_value` attribute and returns it to `__index__` and then it is returned from `__index__` back to what ever called it.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self._value` is an int, calling the `__int__()` method on an int returns the same value, so writing:

```
return self._value.__int__()
```

would do the same as:

```
return self._value
```

And just to prove my point it would be the same as:

```
return int(int(int(int(self._value))))
```

In most cases you can write `__index__` to be a direct alias to the same function:

```
def __int__(self):
    return self._value
__index__ = __int__
```

---

P.S. You may want to look at [PEP 357](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0357/) for the rational of why the `__index__` method exists.

Basically it is to distinguish between objects that can be converted to an `int` and objects that are inherently integers:

```
>>> int(1.3)
1
>>> hex(1.3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#55>", line 1, in <module>
    hex(1.3)
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this. I understood the `__int__` portion, but not `__index__` part, because index does not refer to `_value`, so how does the `__int__` function called by  `__index__`  know to act on `_value`?

Comment: what do you mean _act on `_value`_?  if you do `return self.__int__()` you are calling the `__int__` method and returning it's result, it would be like if you did `def myFunc(x): return math.sqrt(x)` it would _always_ return the same result as directly calling `math.sqrt(x)`, also see [@deceze's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36695699/not-understanding-why-index-method-works/36696282?noredirect=1#comment60979766_36695699)

Comment: This is likely a problem in my understanding of python, so let me lay out how I think things work and you can poke holes in it :) . I'll edit it above.